# React: trigger class method based on redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a class **A**, that is a rich text editor. It holds a `state` that is updated when I write in the text field.

Then I have the component **B** that has a button. When I click the button, I want the component **A** to send text editor data to the server.

Component **B** modifies the Redux state and then this state is passed to the **A** class in props.

How can I then trigger the **A** class to send the data?

1. `componentDidUpdate` works when the state is sent in props and changes but it is also triggered by the text editor, so it sends data every time I write a letter in a text editor
2. `static getDerivedStateFromProps` works the same way `componentDidUpdate` does but seems like a wrong solution because it should be used when the state depends on props. I just want to trigger a class method.

I am using redux. Now it seems I could do this with callback but let's stick to redux with state passed through props (instead of connect, which seem to be another way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `componentDidUpdate` and compare props like this. It only sends data when prop which you passed to the A class.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```